# How to store qt containers inside qt containers

Tags: c++, qt, containers

Do I understand right that it does not make real sense to have

```cpp
QVector<QSharedPointer<QVariantHash>>
```

and that I can stick just to:

```
QVector<QVariantHash>
```

due to implicit sharing?

Honestly, using STL, I would never do like this and would have `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<...>>>`.

UPDATE:

My question is about performance. I understand that it's different ways of storing objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those have different behaviour.

The `QVector<QVariantHash>` is still copy-on-write, so copies of the vector only share elements up to the first modification, whereas so long as you leave the pointers alone, the `QVariantHash`s pointed-to by the elements of `QVector<QSharedPointer<QVariantHash>>` will still be the same objects.

As an aside, I would avoid relying on implicit sharing, because it is really easy to fall into undefined behaviour, with pointers or references being invalidated from underneath you.

I would also caution against overuse of shared pointers. Almost always you can have one thing with unique ownership which hands out references.

Comment: Well, I know this but I ask from the performance point of view. Does it really make sense to keep pointers?

Comment: @JenyaKh No, it makes the most sense to pass references, and not have *either* explicit sharing *nor* implicit sharing

Comment: "I would avoid relying on implicit sharing" -- so you would avoid keeping QVariantHashs values directly. "I would avoid relying on implicit sharing" -- so you would avoid keeping shared pointers. Then what would you keep?

Comment: *One* `std::vector<std::unordered_map<...>>`, and *multiple* (const) `std::vector<std::unordered_map<...>> &`s and / or `vec<map<...>>::iterator` pairs

Comment: I see. Thank you! What do you mean by "... with pointers or references being invalidated from underneath you"?

Comment: e.g. `for (auto & item : function_that_returns_QVector())` detaches the container

Comment: May I ask, I am not convinced about not using shared pointers. Is it about overhead on atomic locks? But in Qt containers I always have to access atomic locks when copy-ing containers (even on shallow /implicit sharing/ copy -- I see it in Qt source code). At the same time, with shared pointers I am safe with preventing a deep copy.

Comment: And honestly, I am confused: you say " I would avoid relying on implicit sharing" but you suggest to keep as `std::vector<std::unordered_map<...>>`. I am sorry.

Comment: @JenyaKh `std::vector<std::unordered_map<...>>` doesn't share ("shallow copy"). A reference is not a shallow copy, it is another name for the same object.

Comment: I avoid shared pointers for two reasons: you have to dereference them, and they share ownership. ~90% of the time you can have one place own by value, ~9% of the time you can use unique_ptr, and only in the 1% do you need shared pointer. Depending on the project, that can be 99% / 0.99% / 0.01%.

Comment: I understand that you suggest to pass a reference. But if you still have to copy the vector -- you will have to have a shallow (qt "implicit sharing") copy (or then maybe even a deep copy). With shared pointers you will have the same but at least without a danger to have a deep copy. Also, btw, if we talk about STL, unordered_map does not have a shallow copy.

Comment: @JenyaKh "shallow copy" is the thing I'm suggesting you avoid. Either deep copy or nothing.

Comment: But all the Qt is based on shallow copies. AFAIU, to make a deep copy of QVector I need to make some effort -- to call a non-const method or something on each of the stored QHashes, -- as by default it will not take place automatically. So do you suggest to use STL instead of Qt containers?

Comment: @JenyaKh yes, don't use QContainers